# Need a mathematical name for a particular conversion.

Tags: reference-request

I can convert 12 into 2 $\def\sf{\sqrt 3}\sf$

But I don't know the correct `mathematical name` for this conversion. can anyone tell me the exact mathematical name for this process and link me to the details of the same.?

Comment: $$12=2^2(\sqrt3)^2$$ Square root

Comment: @labbhattacharjee can you link me to the same.?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_root

Answer (score 3):

The operation that turns the number $12$ into $2\sqrt3$ is the [square root](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_root). One writes $\sqrt{12}=2\sqrt3$.

I gather that you're asking how we get the formal expression $2\sqrt3$ from $\sqrt{12}$. In elementary algebra textbooks, $2\sqrt3$ is called the "simplest radical form" or the "simplified form" of the radical $\sqrt{12}$. There's a little more detail at [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nth_root#Simplified_form_of_a_radical_expression).

Comment: +1 Really thanks for the reference and explanations, what is the mathematical term for the two which is present outside the root and the three which is present inside the root.? I am making a look at the links which was given by you.

Comment: The $3$ inside the root is called the "radicand". I'm not aware of any standard name for the $2$ outside the root.